# Finding an area of a circumference

Tags: math, geometry

I'm developing a radar in which I show some coordinates. But I'm having a math problem I cant resolve. This is the radar:

[image]

It has two areas: the safe area (the white one) and the dangerous area (the red one). The radius of the safe area is 30 and the radius of the complete circumference is 100.

I'm developing a functionality that creates random coordinates in the dangerous zone, but for that, I need to do a random of the X and the Y in that area, and I don't know how to do it. The center is (0,0)

Any tips? Really thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system):

```
float radius = min + rand(max - min); // 30 + rand(0..70)
float angle = rand(-PI, PI)

int x = radius*cos(angle);
int y = radius*sin(angle);
```

Comment: See my comment on Borgleader's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the points to be evenly distributed in both cartesian dimensions then you'll need to pick random x and y coordinates, then discard any result that doesn't fall within the desired area.